# How to get user password to link to WooCommerce / WP Job Manager account?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a password field onto my [WP Job Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/) *Register as a Developer* page. The problem is that it’s not linked to anything, please help!!

What I need help with is to get this password to actually be added to my WooCommerce account.

This has been added via a code snippet.

```
add_filter( 'resume_manager_resume_fields', 
  'wpjms_admin_resume_form_fields' );

function wpjms_admin_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['user_password'] = array(
      'label'       => __( 'Your Password', 'job_manager' ),
      'type'        => 'password',
      'placeholder' => 'password',
      'description' => '',
      'priority'    => 11
    );

    return $fields;

}

// Add field to frontend
add_filter( 'submit_resume_form_fields',
'wpjms_frontend_resume_form_fields' );

function wpjms_frontend_resume_form_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['resume_fields']['user_password'] = array(
      'label'       => __( 'Your Password', 'job_manager' ),
      'type'        => 'password',
      'placeholder' => 'password',
      'required'    => true,
      'description' => '',
      'priority'    => 11
    );

    return $fields;

}
```